# I selected vs. I have selected

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-present-perfect

We got into a grammar discussion at the office.

- > Given I have write-access to a page and **I selected** an option
- > Given I have write-access to a page and **I have selected** an option

1. Are both grammatically correct?
2. Is one is better than the other?

Comment: Either is fine, but present tense would sound a little more natural: "Given I have write access to a page and I select an option."

Comment: I think we need more context, especially since this isn't even an entire sentence.  Can you explain the context?

Comment: @stangdon: It's not a sentence, it's pretty obviously a clause.

Comment: My apologies, we are writing "Gherkin" requirements for a web application. They are clauses in the format of "Given, When, Then" with Given being in the past tense.

Comment: @Robusto - Sure, but that's exactly what makes it harder to say whether it's "correct" - it depends on what else is around it.

Comment: @stangdon: I don't see how. "Given A and B, ..." works with any subsequent declaration or question.

Comment: @Robusto - I dunno, if the continuation of the sentence was "Given I have write access to a page and I selected an option you are a pineapple" is pretty bad.  :-)

Comment: @stangdon: A grammatical sentence doesn't have to make sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, except 'have selected' is present perfect tense. If it was a one time write access and occured in the distant past, then I would use 'I selected'.

However, 'have selected' is more appropriate if it is:

- an action which is still continuing onto the present (do you have to
  keep repeatedly doing this?) e.g. I have been living in this house since..
- a very recent action e.g. I have just eaten...

The present perfect tense is normally used for the above reasons. For example, 'have' is an auxiliary (helping) verb as it adds more information to the main verb 'selected'.